# How to get ArrayList of custom objects from Firestore documents?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to create an ArrayList of objects created from Firestore data. The objects are creating correctly as far as I can tell. When I try to access the ArrayList that I am adding them to though it comes up empty. I get the collection's reference and then add the listener for the query.

```
ArrayList<Doctor> docList = new ArrayList<> (); 
CollectionReference doctors = db.collection("doctors");
doctors.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {

                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                        docList.add(document.toObject(Doctor.class);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

[Firebase APIs are asynchronous](https://medium.com/@CodingDoug/why-are-firebase-apis-asynchronous-callbacks-promises-tasks-e037a6654a93). This means there's no guarantee that your ArrayList will be filled by the time you access it later.

In order to work around this, you can create a separate method where you use the filled ArrayList. You'll call this method from your `OnCompleteListener` because you know that it has already been filled in the Listener.

```java
doctors.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) { 
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    ArrayList<Doctor> docList = new ArrayList<> ();
                    for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                        docList.add(document.toObject(Doctor.class);
                    }
                    doSomethingWithArray(docList);
                }
            }
        });

// ... rest of your code ...


// the new method to process the received arraylist
public void doSomethingWithArray(ArrayList<Doctor> docList) {
    // do whatever you need to do with the array list
}
```